# Python: Can i assert that a value is within a certain percentage of another

Tags: python

I want to be able to check that two variables are withing a certain percentage of each , so for example if i have

```
value1 = 200 
value2 = 210
```

i want to check that if value 2 is greater than 10% bigger than value1 an warning error will be thrown is this possible to do in python code?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Yes, this can be done in Python code. It's just maths. How would you do this on paper?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  Check that the absolute value of their difference, as a proportion of your base value, is less than 0.10 (i.e. 10%).

```
abs( (value1 - value2) / float(value1) ) <= 0.10
```

Comment: Or `abs((value1 - value2) / float(value1)) <= 0.10` if it runs on Python 2.